# C# for loop. Index was outside the bounds

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

The for loop code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listEquipment.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[EquipmentItems] ([RequestID], [TypeID]) VALUES (@RequestID, @TypeID)", conn);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userRequest;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@TypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (listEquipment.SelectedItems[i] as Equipment).equipmentID;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The line with the error:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (listEquipment.SelectedItems[i] as Equipment).equipmentID;
```

Please help! I'm new to programming.

Comment: `listEquipment.Items.Count` >= `listEquipment.SelectedItems.Count`

Comment: could u plz show your items inside `listEquipment`?

Comment: Also, i guess you want to loop all, so use `i < listEquipment.Items.Count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You loop all items and then access that index in `listEquipment.SelectedItems[i]`. But there are probably not all items selected which means that this collection is smaller and you can't access it.

So i assume that you dont want to loop all items but only the selected, so use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listEquipment.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for (int i = 0; i < listEquipment.Items.Count - 1; i++)
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listEquipment.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made the change

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this (let me expailn via comments in the code below):

```
  //DONE: make sql readable 
  string sql = 
    @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[EquipmentItems] (
        [RequestID], 
        [TypeID]) 
      VALUES (
        @RequestID, 
        @TypeID)";

  // Create command once - use many (within the loop)
  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using  
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
    // user request is the same for all the equipment
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userRequest;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TypeID", SqlDbType.Int);

    //DONE: foreach + OfType<> is by far more readable in the context: 
    //     "for each selected equipment execute a query"
    foreach (Equipment equipment in listEquipment.SelectedItems.OfType<Equipment>()) {
      cmd.Parameters["@TypeID"].Value = equipment.equipmentID;

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
  }
```